# How can I export all results from Blazegraph into a file?

Tags: export, blazegraph

I would like to export the results of my SPARQL query from Blazegraph into a file. However, it exports only the first page of the results. When I try to display all results, my browser crashes.

How can I fix this?

I'm running Blazegraph 2.1.2 on a local cluster.

Comment: How did you do the export? And what did you try to display all results? Such information might help readers in order to help you. Please consider [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38437787/edit) your question in order to provide some details.

Answer (score 1):

To export results you can rely on `curl` and query your SPARQL endpoint through command line like this:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9999/bigdata/namespace/YOUR_NAMESPACE/sparql --data-urlencode 'query=SELECT * WHERE{ ?s p ?o } LIMIT 1' --data-urlencode 'format=json' > outputfile
```

You have to specify your endpoint's address of course and your query as you want. This is just an example but it may give you an idea.

Also you can modify your expected output format (CSV, XML, JSON, etc) and include headers if you want.

[Here](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/REST_API#QUERY) you can read more about it.

Comment: Thanks aquiros, that works! Blazegraph's web interface does provide an export-results feature (at least mine does).

Comment: I haven't tried yet the 2.1.2 version so maybe that's it. I'm updating my answer. If it worked for you please consider accepting it. @Fabian_G

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download all your graph you should use a `CONSTRUCT` query:

```
curl --X POST \
  --url 'https://{host}/bigdata/namespace/{namespace}/sparql' \
  --data-urlencode 'query=CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } where { ?s ?p ?o }' \
  --header 'Accept: application/x-turtle' > outputfile.ttl
```

In this case I am exporting it in a turtle format.